# extract jomsocial 2.8 fields

Tags: php, joomla, jomsocial

How should i extract fields from jomsocial (latest version 2.8) so i can showcase anywhere else in the profile? i'm planning to re-design the profile page.

I tried with this code in the profile.about.php but couldn't get it to function.

```
<?php
$data = array( 'type' => 'textarea' , 'value' => $user->getInfo('FIELD_ABOUTME') );
CFactory::load( 'libraries' , 'profile' );
$value = CProfileLibrary::getFieldData( $data );
?>
<?php echo $value; ?>
```

Got error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getInfo() on a non-object in

I'm using jomsocial 2.8 and joomla 2.5.

Comment: why would anyone dislike this post? :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
        $data = array( 'type' => 'textbox' , 'value' => $member->getInfo('FIELD_COMPANY_NAME') );
        CFactory::load( 'libraries' , 'profile' );
        $value = CProfileLibrary::getFieldData( $data );
     ?>
        <?php echo $value; ?>
```

Comment: it's not working out onlineplaner. It gives me an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getInfo() on a non-object in ...the first line of this code.

Answer (score 1):

Jomsocial documentation recommends using the following code to get user field data, probably because its field values are set up a bit different in the database.

```
$user = CFactory::getUser($userId);
$data = $user->getInfo('FIELD_CODE');
```

Comment: Nothing shows up when i add your code in profile.about.php

    <?php 
    $user = CFactory::getUser($userId);
    $data = $user->getInfo('FIELD_ABOUTME');
    ?>